# collision detection on multiple canvas layers

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, collision-detection

I am struggling on figuring out how to detect collisions on assets drawn on different canvas layers. I have made two arrays that hold the stuff I want to "collide" with called collidable_objects_layer1 and collidable_objects_layer2. These arrays basically draw the tables and the wall in the back which the character should not be able to pass through.

bar.js basically holds the whole bar "scene" you see in the link below. and main.js is the loop that makes my player move. I think my architecture is all messed up cause I don't see an easy way to tie these two together so any advice on that(are modules necessary here or are they just hurting me?). the way it is now I am not sure how I add more "scenes" with different collision testing.

I'm assuming the collision testing happens in the main loop

```
function main() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = (now - last_time) / 1000.0;

    clearCanvas();
    drawCharacter();
    frame++;
    last_time = now;
    requestAnimFrame(main);
}
```

**so a couple questions really, what would the algorithm(psuedocode) look like to have my player detect these collidable objects in bar.js. second, is my architecture appropriate to handle multiple scenes, for example, once the player leaves the "bar" to "outside" (outside.js) how can I handle that transition so my player can detect objects regardless of its "scene". I was thinking I end up with a Scene class or something, I am not sure.**

thanks in advance. find the plunk link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/YHVUkKHk2IXZu9WC5TW2)

Answer (score 1):

### Creating an object interface.

The object `bar` and `player` are both global in your example so accessing one from the other is no issue. Ie inside `player` you can call `bar();` which will init the bar.

What you want to do is provide a more extensive interface to the scene object `bar`. This interface provides access to the object in a controlled way (via functions).

First lets look at what is needed.

When the player moves we would like to know if the way is clear. If not then don't move, if so then move. Thus we need a function that returns `true` or `false` for a given position depending on what is at that position.

**The interface**

I will only add pseudo code here, you can workout the details.

In your `bar` object rather than return the function `init` return an object that will be the public interface to the object `bar`

```
var bar = (function(){
    //... all the code and function

    return {   // return a interface object
       init : init,  // with the function init
    };
})();
```

Now the object `bar` has properties as methods. To init `bar`

```
bar.init(); // rather than bar() as you had it.
```

**Extending the interface**

To extend the interface to `bar` with a collision test you add a function inside `bar` to test a given position

```
var bar = (function(){
    //... all the code and function
    function isPositionBlocked(x,y){ // returns true if location x y 
                                     // if blocked
         //... code to find what is at x,y
         if(blocked){
             return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
```

and then add that function to the returned interface object.

```
    return {   // return an object
       init : init,  // with the function init
       test : isPositionBlocked, // with the new test function.
    };
})();
```

Now you can access the test function from within the `player` object (assuming the `player` has access to the object `bar`)

From inside `player`

```
  // movex movey are the directions to move
  // posx, posy are the current direction
  if(! bar.test(posx + mousex, posy + movey)){ // if not blocked
      posx += movex;
      posy += movey;
  }
```

That is how you access details between objects when using immediately invoked objects `var obj = (function(){...code; return {}})();`

**Alternative implementations**

You can also create the interface object inside `bar` letting you access the interface from within `bar`.

```
var bar = (function(){
    //... all the code and functions
    var API = {};
    API.init = function(){ //... init code
    API.test = function(x,y){ //... blah blah

    function someInternalFunction(){
        var result = API.test(x,y);  // access the interface from 
                                           // within the bar object
    }
    return API;
})();
```

I use the acronym API (Application Protocol Interface) as the prefered name `interface` is a reserved word in Javascript, but any name is ok. The `API` object can contain anything you want outside objects to have access to (in other languages these are called `public` properties) and everything inside the object `bar` that you do not want to give outside access to is `private` though in javascript these terms are generally not used.

**'this' is bound to the interface**

When you add a function to an object

```
API.test = function(x,y){...
```

it is automatically bound to that object and thus you can access the object via the `this` token.

EG inside test

```
API.init = function(){//...
API.test = function(x,y){//...
    this.init(); // if you wanted to init
    // this refers to the object API
```

Thus if you use the direct return object

```
 return {
    init : init,
    test : testFunction,
 }
```

you can still get access to the properties of the returned object via `this`

```
var test = (function(){
     function init(){};
     function testFunction(){
        if(this.init){  
           return true;
        }
     }
     return {
        init : init,
        test : testFunction,
     }
})();

console.log(test.test()); // output >> true;
```

But calling the function `testfunction` from inside the object can have unpredictable results as it is not bound to the interface object, so be carefull. I generally create the `API` object and only define public functions as part of that object to prevent calling them incorrectly.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response it is much appreciated. In bar.js I am already returning an interfacing object with an init function, I think you may have overlooked that.

Comment: @atsituab From memory I though you only returned the init function, but then I may have missed that. I was not sure what you question was about so I presumed it was about how to get access to an object's functionally from another, not actually a problem of collisions. If I am wrong I can remove the answer.